# Performing A Query On Field Generated From Sub Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, Clients and Jobs.

I am doing a report on clients, and as part of the query, I also return a count of how many jobs we have done for each client. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT * ,  
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Jobs WHERE ClientID = Clients.ID) AS JobsCount
FROM Clients
```

I now need to modify this to allow conditional queries based on the JobsCount, such as "return all clients with more than 100 jobs". Simply adding a where clause on JobsCount doesnt seem to work - `Invalid column name 'JobsCount'.`

How can i query on a column that is generated through a sub query?

Comment: Switch that condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `HAVING` clause and I think you'll be in business.

Comment: Are you using this query inside a subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add where condition as below:

```
Select *, (select count(*) from Jobs where ClientId = t.Id ) as JobsCount 
    from Clients t where (select count(*) from Jobs where ClientId = t.Id) > 100
```

Or other simple way to wrap it into another subquery as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, (select count(*) from Jobs where ClientId = t.Id ) as JobsCount 
    from Clients t
    ) a Where JobsCount > 100
```

Comment: The second option, wrapping it into a sub query worked great! Strange that you cant query on a sub query, but can query on a sub query within a query...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the correlated subquery you are currently using to find the number of jobs per client, other than that it won't run fast or scale well, is that it is difficult to apply a restriction on the number of jobs.  Instead, you can rephrase your query as a join between `Clients` and a subquery which finds the number of jobs per each client.  Then, a simple `WHERE` clause restriction can restrict clients based on how many jobs they have.

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    COALESCE(t2.jobCount, 0) AS jobCount
FROM Clients t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.ID, COUNT(*) AS jobCount
    FROM Clients t1
    INNER JOIN Jobs t2
        ON t1.ID = t2.ClientID
    GROUP BY t1.ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.jobCount > 100    -- or whatever restrictions you want
```

Comment: @KannanKandasamy No, the original query is working AFAIK.  The question is how can we restrict it to the number of jobs.  The short answer is, you can't if you phrase it using a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select clients.* ,jobcount  
from clients 
inner join 
(Select COUNT(*) as jobcount,clientid FROM Jobs group by clientid having count(*)>100 )Jobs
On jobs.clientid=clients.clientid
```

Grouping the job count and filtering | removing using having condition with job count >100. Inner join will filter | removing the clients with job count <100 or client doesn't exists with Jobs table.